# UIPanGestureRecognizer and 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a view with a UIPanGestureRecognizer and 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizers (one for left, and one for right).

The problem I am running into is that the UIPanGestureRecognizer always overrides the swipes.

What I want is that the swipe should override the pan...is this possible, or do I need to find a different way of doing things.

FYI - to explain why I need this, I have a set of cards that I am drawing out of a deck.  The card that was drawn is shown to the user (the artwork for that).  Now, there is additional information that I need to relay to the user (card name, details, etc.).  I basically hid a bunch of UILabels behind a UIImageView and I change the alpha setting of the image view to show the text.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method to make sure that one recognizer is only fired after another has failed, so in this case:

```
[panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

btw, you only need 1 swipe recognizer, the direction property is a bit mask so you can set it to

```
swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight
```

and it will recognize both directions

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  I didn't know that the direction was a flag like that.  I will still need two for my purposes though...